# Getting Invalid Provider Exception in Vinelab/minion in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I use [Vinelab/minion](https://github.com/Vinelab/minion) plugin to get notification in my `client app ( angularjs )` from `server ( Laravel 4.2 )`, I implement [autobahn.js](http://autobahn.ws/js/) at client side, but when i implement `Vinelab/minion` library in `Laravel` and trying to run minion by calling `php artisan minion:run` it give me error like

```
[Vinelab\Minion\InvalidProviderException]
 Provider Vinelab\Minion\ChatProvider must be an instance of \Vinelab\Minion\Provider
```

**My Directory Structure:**

```
app/
 config/
  packages/
   vinelab/
    minion/
     minion.php
 providers/
  ChatProvider.php
vendor/
```

and in `app/config/packages/vinelab/minion/minion.php`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Router Realm
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The realm that the router should use.
    |
    */
    'realm' => 'minion',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Router Host
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The IP or hostname that the router should run under.
    |
    */
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Router Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The port that should be used by the router.
    |
    */
    'port' => 9090,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Auto-registered Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The providers listed here will be automatically registered on the
    | session start of the router, in return their role is to register RPCs,
    | subscribe and publish to topics and pretty much whatever an Internal Client does.
    |
    */
    'providers' => [

        'ChatProvider'

    ],

    'debug' => true,

];
```

and in **providers/ChatProvider.php**

```
<?php

use Vinelab\Minion\Provider;

class ChatProvider extends Provider {

    protected $prefix = 'order.';

    public function boot()
    {
        // will be registered to topic: chat.send
        $this->register('send', 'sendMessage');
    }

    public function sendMessage($args, $data)
    {
        $message = $data->message;

        // store message in the database

        // tell everyone about it
        $this->publish('message', compact('message'));

        // response with the status
        return true;
    }
    }
}
```

I check for various name space and lot of things but i can not solve this.

I also post this issue on [github](https://github.com/Vinelab/minion/issues/2) but not found any answer.

Is it perfect or any other way to do this?

Help me, It will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my extended class.

```
<?php

namespace Chaospower\Messaging\Provider;

use Vinelab\Minion\Provider;
use Auth;

class ChatProvider extends Provider
{
    protected $prefix = 'com.';

    public function boot()
    {
        // will be registered to topic: chat.send
        $this->register(Config::get('site.domain').'.message', 'sendMessage');
    }

    public function setPrefix($prefix)
    {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
    }

    public function sendMessage($args, $data)
    {
        $message = $data->message;

        // store message in the database?

        // tell everyone about it
        $this->publish('message', compact('message'));

        // response with the status
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think you're missing namespace somewhere. Because the error is pointing to Vinelab\Minion\ChatProvider. It must be namespace\ChatProvider.

Output should be like below

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Laravel$ php artisan minion:run --register="Chaospower\Messaging\Provider\ChatProvider"

           ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
        ▄▀▀═════════════▀▀▄
       █═══════════════════█
      █═════════════════════█
     █═══▄▄▄▄▄▄▄═══▄▄▄▄▄▄▄═══█
    █═══█████████═█████████═══█
    █══██▀    ▀█████▀    ▀██══█
   ██████  █▀█  ███  █▀█  ██████
   ██████  ▀▀▀  ███  ▀▀▀  ██████
    █══▀█▄    ▄██ ██▄    ▄█▀══█
    █════▀█████▀   ▀█████▀════█
    █═════════════════════════█
    █═════════════════════════█
    █═══════▀▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▀═══════█
    █═════════════════════════█
   ▐▓▓▌═════════════════════▐▓▓▌
   ▐▐▓▓▌▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▐▓▓▌▌
   █══▐▓▄▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▄▓▌══█
  █══▌═▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▌═▐══█
  █══█═▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▓▓▓▓▓▓▌═█══█
  █══█═▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▐██▀██▌▓▓▓▓▓▓▌═█══█
  █══█═▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▀▀▀▀▀▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▌═█══█
  █══█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█══█
 ▄█══█▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▌█══█▄
 █████▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▌ █████
 ██████▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▌ ██████
  ▀█▀█  ▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▌   █▀█▀
         ▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▌▐▓▓▓▓▓▓▌
          ▐▓▓▓▓▌  ▐▓▓▓▓▌
         ▄████▀    ▀████▄
         ▀▀▀▀        ▀▀▀▀
2015-03-10T08:27:58.5390490 info       [Vinelab\Minion\Client 5446] New client created
2015-03-10T08:27:58.5467130 info       [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 5446] Starting Transport
2015-03-10T08:27:58.7215050 info       [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 5446] Pawl has connected
2015-03-10T08:27:58.8066330 debug      [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 5446] Received: [2,837176922,{"authrole":"anonymous","authmethod":"anonymous","roles":{"broker":{"features":{"publisher_identification":true,"publisher_exclusion":true,"pattern_based_subscription":true,"subscription_meta_api":true,"subscriber_blackwhite_listing":true}},"dealer":{"features":{"progressive_call_results":true,"pattern_based_registration":true,"registration_meta_api":true,"shared_registration":true,"caller_identification":true}}},"authid":"RK7RIery7evd71THp_Kzcx3h"}]
2015-03-10T08:27:58.8109340 debug      [Vinelab\Minion\Client 5446] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\WelcomeMessage]
2015-03-10T08:27:58.8110330 info       [Vinelab\Minion\Client 5446] We have been welcomed...
2015-03-10T08:27:58.8292430 debug      [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 5446] Received: [65,1474724289953122,1308617500]
2015-03-10T08:27:58.8347220 debug      [Vinelab\Minion\Client 5446] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\RegisteredMessage]
2015-03-10T08:27:58.8350070 info       [Thruway\Role\Callee 5446] Setting registration_id for com.leadrm.app.message (0)
2015-03-10T08:27:58.8354950 debug      [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 5446] Received: [33,2002512864967000,1374387471]
2015-03-10T08:27:58.8401330 debug      [Vinelab\Minion\Client 5446] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\SubscribedMessage]
2015-03-10T08:28:05.0705930 debug      [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 5446] Received: [36,1374387471,1952879835,{},["test"]]
2015-03-10T08:28:05.0930590 debug      [Vinelab\Minion\Client 5446] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\EventMessage]
2015-03-10T08:36:11.6339470 debug      [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 5446] Received: [36,1374387471,1879215773,{},["test"]]
2015-03-10T08:36:11.6341770 debug      [Vinelab\Minion\Client 5446] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\EventMessage]
2015-03-10T08:36:18.9851460 debug      [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 5446] Received: [36,1374387471,851409442,{},["test"]]
2015-03-10T08:36:18.9854340 debug      [Vinelab\Minion\Client 5446] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\EventMessage]
```

`$this->register` is different form subscription. It's a remote method call procedure.

If you need to subscribe `$this->subscribe('message','callbackfunction')` then it will prepare the onMessage function from thruway.

It's either you set the provider as a remote procedure registrant or subscribe to topics. session.call sendMessage when you need to send messages.